# :eq() selector returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and I get this 'undefined' error when using `:eq()` selector. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>:eq() selector example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button>Button #1</button>
        <button>Button #2</button>
        <button>Button #3</button>
        <button>Button #4</button>
        <button>Button #5</button>
        <button>Button #6</button>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the script:

```
var myButton = $('button:eq(5)');
console.log(myButton.textContent);
```

When I use `var myButton = $('button')[5];` everything is fine though.

Comment: you need to use `text()` there

Comment: `:eq()` and `.eq()` both yield a jQuery object, whereas `[]` yields a DOM node. In your example, `button:eq(5)` doesn't return undefined, it returns something that doesn't have `textContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('button:eq(5)')` return jQuery object that doesn't have `textContent` property so you should use `text()` instead to get the element text :

```
var myButton = $('button:eq(5)');
console.log(myButton.text());
```

When `$('button')[5];` return DOM object that why you could access the property `textContent` on it :

```
var myButton = $('button')[5];
console.log(myButton.textContent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't gotten to the jQuery methods yet :) Is using `$('button')[5];` a good practice?

Comment: You're welcome, it will be better if you don't use jquery if you want to get DOM object it's better to use `document.querySelectorAll('button')[5]` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Do with jquery object [`text()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia-u6az6bUAhVCtY8KHTpDB6wQFggxMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ftext%2F&usg=AFQjCNH_op1krIyMiANGFM-1-_RiNyug6w&sig2=jYkOBD4cMX9oEBLHqmav1Q).selector`$('button:eq(5)');` return a jquery Object .And `textContent` is a Dom Object. is not acceptable one .

```js
var myButton = $('button:eq(5)');
console.log(myButton.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Button #1</button>
  <button>Button #2</button>
  <button>Button #3</button>
  <button>Button #4</button>
  <button>Button #5</button>
  <button>Button #6</button>
</div>
```

**OR**

If you need combination of both try like this

```
$('button:eq(5)')[0].textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('button')[5]` return a reference of DOM element which has `textContent` property thus it works.

However `$('button:eq(5)')` is a jQuery object which doesn't have the property thus *undefined* is returned.

Use `.text()` function with jQuery object.

```
var text = $('button:eq(5)').text()
```